# Curl не сохраняет cookie

Tags: php, curl

Написал curl код авторизации. Но при попытке авторизации пишет:

*Ошибка: Пожалуйста, включите cookie и попробуйте ещё раз*

Почему он может не создаваться и не записываться?

```
<?php
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$url = 'https://cp.hosting.ru/manager/billmgr';
$auth = 'username=juggernaut&password=12345&theme=sirius&lang=ru&func=auth'.
        '&project=&welcomfunc=&welcomparam=';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://cp.hosting.ru/manager/billmgr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $auth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ____DIR____ . "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ____DIR____ . "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 6):

Возможные причины получения сообщения о неустановленных cookie:

Обратите внимание на путь к файлу cookie.txt, возможно это опечатка, но у вас указана константа `____DIR____`, с четырьмя символами подчеркивания до и после DIR, это не верно, их должно быть два `__DIR__`.

Возможно в коде у вас все верно и это особенности форматирования кода. Однако, константа `__DIR__` возвращает путь без последнего слеша. Т.е. вы получаете путь вида /path/to/www. Когда же вы объединяете его с cookie.txt, у вас получается путь /path/to/wwwcookie.txt. Поэтому строки

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ____DIR____ . "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ____DIR____ . "cookie.txt");
```

следует заменить на

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
```

Убедитесь, что файл cookie.txt создается в текущей директории. Возможно у пользователя, из под которого выполняется PHP-скрипт не достаточно прав для создания файлов в директории выполнения скрипта.